# why i cannot execute my alert javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert

can anyone help me? i've got a silly question. i try to make an alert function using js but it doesnt execute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".delete").click(function(){
    alert("Are you sure?");
  });
</script>
```

and this is my delete button

```
<td><a class=\"btn delete btn-danger\" href='".base_url().'admin/blog/deleteblog/1'."'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: classic noob error, you put your script in the htlm head part ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why you have used the \ around your class name here, but one is within the quotes and one outside. I would remove these.

> "btn delete btn-danger"

```
 <td>
    <a class="btn delete btn-danger" href='".base_url().'admin/blog/deleteblog/1'."'>
       Delete
    </a>
</td>
```

As for your script, you should check if the document is ready before using JQuery - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function(){
            alert("Are you sure?");
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I think the quotes are fine - from the use of `.` later they appear to be using PHP and this is clearly a double-quoted string, so using `\"` to escape double-quotes that you want in the output is correct. Of course there are better and more readable ways to get this output but I see no evidence of an actual mistake here.

Comment: Well observed, perhaps it could be second issue of the document not being ready prior to the on click.

Comment: I agree that's one of the likely causes of this issue. But there's really not enough to go on in the question as posed to be sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine in the example below for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <td><a class="btn delete btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a></td>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(".delete").click(function () {
      alert("Are you sure?");
    });
  </script>
</html>
```